# Stop webapplication in tomcat using java code

Tags: tomcat

I use HttpClient. I developed web application using JSF. deployed into tomcat6.0.29.
I am trying to stop the application. But its not working.

../conf/tomcat-users.xml  file content

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
      <tomcat-users>
          <role rolename="manager"/>
          <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager" />
     </tomcat-users>
```

My java code is

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;
import java.io.*;
public class HttpClientTutorial
{
private static String url = "http://localhost:8080/manager/html/stop?path=/jsfproject";
public static void main(String[] args)
{        
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER,
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));
   try{

        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
        }

        byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

        System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
    }
    catch (HttpException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {            
        method.releaseConnection();
    }
}  
}
```

But i got the error like this

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Method failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Also i got

```
401 Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed any configuration `files, please examine the file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation.

That file will contain the credentials to let you use this webapp.
ou will need to add manager role to the config file listed above. For example:

<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager"/>

For more information - please see the Manager App HOW-TO.
```

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to stop the application, Tomcat needs the credentials of the user you created in tomcat-users.xml, but your code makes no attempt to supply them.

Here's some clode which might give you a clue:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpState state = client.getState();

// Set credentials on the client
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("tomcat","s3cret");
state.setCredentials( null, null, credentials );

HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. state.setCredentials(null, null, credentials); this method is deprecated. Is there any alternative method for setCredentials(,,)